# Lightscribe not working on DVD drive (model number "ggw-h20l")

Tags: windows-8

The DVD works fine but lightscribe is not working. The error I received is something like "no lightscribe disk in drive", and it then ejects the disk.

I tried updating firmware, but received the same issue. I then tried 2 more disks, but that did not work either. I even tried different software that I confirmed to be working because I used it on a separate lightscribe different drive, but this still did not solve the problem.

On a side note, this is a new DVD drive.

Comment: We need more information.

Comment: I think we have enough information, but the horrendous grammar made it difficult to understand. I have fixed the grammar for you and answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several problems. Here are a couple:

- The drive could be faulty. Since it is new, my suggestion would be to first just take it back to the store and exchange for a new one. This is the easiest fix.
- The discs you are using may not be lightscribe capable. WIthout knowing what discs you are using, there is no way for me to be certain.

Keep in mind that regular discs will not work. Lightscribe requires specific discs which are compatible with lightscribe. You must go to the store and buy "Lightscribe Compatible" discs.

Note: I wasn't very happy either the first time I discovered this! As a result I've never used lightscribe, despite having several lightscribe-capable DVD burners. I never had the lightscribe discs and didn't have enough desire to buy some.